# Can i use email verification function and Login With google in one project. (in django)

Tags: python, django, google-signin, email-verification

I try to make a website that have email verification and login with google function, so first i make email verification function, and it work and then i try to make login with google function but when I see in the tutorial, there can only be 1 function, namely choosing a verification email or logging in with google, because the verification email section I made with a custom auth system, while logging in with google in the tutorial uses the default auth system from a package. If you can use both, how?

this is my views.py(my login and register function)

```
class RegistrationView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'app/register.html',{'form':form})
    def post(self, request):
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request,'Selamat Akun kamu telah Teregistrasi. Silahkan lihat email untuk memverifikasi')
            form.save()
        
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        send_activation_email(user,request)
        return redirect('registration')  

class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'app/login.html',{'form':form})
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        
        if user and not user.is_email_verified:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                                 'Email mu belum terverifikasi silahkan lihat inbox email mu')
            return redirect('login')
            
        if not user:
            messages.error(request,'Password atau Username Salah')
            return redirect('login')
        
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('profile')
```

and i look the login with google code in this article
[User Registration in django using Google OAuth](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-google-oauth/)

Comment: Use [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)
or if working with DRF , use [djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser)

Comment: I've tried using the package but it doesn't work, there's a conflict with my custom auth stytem script

Comment: Please post the specific `conflict` you are facing, we can try to resolve that.

Comment: in my project i use custom auth system, in that article use a default auth system from OAuth Package(and i dont know how to edit the auth system from that package)